# Batch file error when listing websites using appcmd

Tags: batch-file

I am getting some kind of error when using the following statement in a batch file:

```
FOR /F %f IN ('C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd list site /text:name /bindings:') DO rmdir /s/q "D:\Websites\%f"
```

The same code works fine when run manually in a cmd window.

The window won't stay open to see the error even if I use pause at the end. ANy ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double the `%` on every mention of the metavariable `%f`. Single-`%` works directly from the prompt, double within a batch file.